# $_GET['m'] gives no result on archive page with permalink set to postname

Tags: wordpress

I am extending the archive feature to get my **CUSTOM TABLE CONTENTS** too . For this I need the month and year for which posts are retrieved.

With default permalink settings , i am able to get it with $_GET['m'] but when I changed permalink settings to postname, it gives no results.

So how can i get it now ?

Comment: Just use `the_date()` inside your loop... You don't need to go through the URL and $_GET to retrieve this value. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date

Comment: @barakadam i am not getting the date of an archive, i am trying to get the date on the basis of which i will get my custom table data

Comment: if you were getting this date from the URL then it means either it was the date from an archive or the date from a post, no? Can you give me your URL structure before you changed permalink or at least a URL so I understand?

Comment: After changing : http://localhost/magazinechild/2012/10/

Before : http://localhost/magazinechild/?m=201210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether it is the right way to do that or not but i got it working this way :

```
    $curr_query = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], -8, 7);
    $curr_date = explode('/', $curr_query);
    $year = $curr_date[0];
    $month = $curr_date[1];
```

And then pass month and year to my function and displayed the results.